# how dependent bindings in let are evaluated?

Tags: haskell

Is it safe to use bindings that depend on each other in `let`? For example:

```
let x = 1
    y = x + 2
in y
```

Is it possible that they are evaluated in parallel? my `ghci` shows that it is evaluated correctly, but will this be always the case?

Comment: With GHC, things are only evaluated in parallel if you ask for it (and sometimes not even then). Other compilers may differ. Answering your other question, though, requires some care: what does "evaluated correctly" mean, specifically? Perhaps part of my clarification question would be answered by saying what you are afraid might go wrong. ("They are evaluated in parallel" doesn't appear to me to be something going wrong.)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Haskell is lazy evaluated. This means that expressions are only evaluated by necessity. Let's start with your example.

```
let x = 1
    y = x + 2
in y
```

The system looks at the `y` part (the expression), and says "Hey. I know what `y` equals. It equals `x + 2`" But it can only evaluate `x + 2` if it has a definition for `x`, so it does the same thing and decides that `y` is `1 + 2` which is of course `3`. Now this is only a small portion of the power of lazy evaluation. The next example shows it more fully.

```
let x = 0 : y
    y = 1 : x
in take 50 x
```

This expression will evaluate correctly, yielding the first fifty elements on the list `x`, which will be `0` and `1` alternating. Both of the values `x` and `y` are infinite lists that depend on each other, and indeed in most languages this would overflow the stack. However, the evaluation rules allow the system to only see the parts it needs, which in that example is the first fifty elements.

So to answer your question about evaluation order, the system evaluates what it sees. If the function is supposed to return `y`, it evaluates `y` and then as necessary `x`. If you had put `x` in your first example, it would have evaluated `x` and left `y` alone. For example, this code will not err.

```
let x = 1
    y = error "I'm an error message!"
in x
```

This is because the `y` form is never needed, so the piece of code that would crash the program is never even looked at.

Comment: Haskell is not necessarily lazily evaluated, but whatever order the implementation picks will give the same result as lazy evaluation.

Comment: @augustss You are absolutely correct, sir. To be more specific, Haskell is non-strict, which happens to be implemented as lazy evaluation.

Answer (score 2):

In Haskell (regardless of whether you use a single `let`, multiple `let`s, `case`, `where` or function parameters) an expression is evaluated when the evaluation of another expression depends on its value.

So in your case, as soon as `y`'s value is required (which of course depends on the surrounding program), `y` will be evaluated and `x` will be evaluated as part of `y`'s evaluation.

Another way to think of it is this: whenever you use the value of a variable, it will be evaluated at that point at the latest. That is it might have been evaluated previously (if it was needed previously) or it might be evaluated now, but, as long as you do use the value, it will never not be evaluated. So, except for performance reasons, there's no need to worry about when a variable will be evaluated.